# Is tag-based database storage a good idea?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm working on a social network-like software where I have a database with a **person table**:

```
Person
--------
id
firstname
lastname
mail
birthday
[etc.]
```

Now the problem is that **I want to enable the user to add very detailed info**. For example what tattoos the person has, and where, and what size and so on. With the current database layout I'd have to add another **table for the tattoos**:

```
Tattoo
--------
id
fk_person
size
position
[etc.]
```

Now `tattoo` is **not the only new table** I'd like to add, there are others for hair, piercings, music taste and so on.

So now to get to the question: Would it not be a good idea to **store all that data in a single `Tag` table** like this:

```
Tag
--------
id
tag_name
tag_value
```

There I could add data like this:

```
1 | tattoo_size | large
2 | tattoo_size | medium
3 | tattoo_size | small
4 | firstname | Peter
5 | nickname | Pete
7 | birthday | 11.11.1999
```

Plus an n-to-n-table `Person` to `Tag`.

```
id
fk_person
fk_tag
```

With data like this:

```
1 | 25 | 1
2 | 25 | 4
3 | 23 | 1
```

This way there is **no redundant information** if two people have a large tattoo or the firstname Peter for example and the people can have as many tattoos as they want.

An additional bonus this seems to bring is that **searching would be easier**: You just have to run a `SELECT` on the `Tag` table with the keyword.

I'm using MySQL and PHP in case that matters.

**Good idea?** Bad idea? Got a better idea?

**Thanks**

Comment: I added a "Tag" to your question.  Search for other questions there.  I am weary of ranting against EAV.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be able to query things like "all people with tattoos and piercings" then you will have to structure this as a many-to-many between people and tags. You can namespace your tags either as a column in the tags table like `category='body',name='piercing', or you can bake that information into the tag itself, like`body.piercing` if you can keep the naming simple enough to avoid potential conflict with your separator(s).

If you don't need to query these things in an aggregate way, just use a [JSON column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) and store your data there. You have a ton of flexibility as to how you organize this without having to create lots and lots of tables.

The risk here is creating a structure that's too generic will leave you with a really crappy document store. If you're going down that road, evaluate solutions like [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) as well.